# Does Cochrane-Armitage test require an obvious trend in contingency table?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, contingency-tables

I'm trying to determine whether it's appropriate to use the Cochrane-Armitage trend test on this set of data? I don't have any specific hypotheses I need to investigate, just to choose an appropriate test to look for a significant difference.

I've attached the contingency table. There is an observed trend in the latter 3 categories but not in the first. Do you need an obvious observed trend throughout the data in order to warrant using CA?

[image: Agegroups/longcommute]

Answer (score 0):

The C-A test looks for a trend over all the ordinal categories. It seems to be a reasonable approach in this situation.

But note that it's testing if the trend is different across the dichotomous category variable.  It looks like the trend is similar for both categories of *Longcommute*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ah okay, are the trends in proportions in each category not polar opposites because of it's mutually-exclusive nature? My other option was Pearson's X2, but I felt like that wouldn't take advantage of the ordinal nature of the data, would it be a better option?

Comment: A chi-square test of association answers a different question.  (Essentially, by treating *AgeGroup* as a nominal variable rather than an ordinal variable).  You can do this, if this is the question you want to answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment on polar opposites and mutually-exclusive.  With the C-A test, if the data for *Yes* were 100, 50, 25, 12, 6, and for *No* were 6, 12, 25, 50, 100, then the suggestion would be that the trends were different across *Longcommute*.

Comment: I think it would also help if you calculate the proportion in each cell within each column.  That is, the proportions of *AgeGroup* within *No* is 3%, 23%, 15%, 59%.  You can compare these to the proportions within *Yes*.